# Improvement to the classification and labeling in a list of mathematical references

Tags: reference-request

I'm the maintainer of the [Hyper-complex number List](https://archive.org/details/hyper_number_4_8),
I am searching for some help in respect of the categorization, clasification regarding the List. I really like references in the line of the List, but here, certainly I am looking for alternatives ways of clasification while grouping the references of the list. The other reason I am came here and not, for example, Math Overflow, Mathematics or some other forum is because here is more probably to find people with a god grasp in mathematical references from the past and the present with a much much bigger mathematical scope than me, or, with very different background. Not quite sure if there are some helpful tags to this question. At some point in the future, the list will become a wiki, but for now will keep its current format. What other possible categories you may see?, some clear weaknesses or voids in the classification? Some other category in the line of the works that may fit in the list? or some other vein that I may exploit?

Best regards, Pyra

**Update** : I was able to dedicate a couple of days to experiment with the classification for [the version 5.3](https://archive.org/details/hyper_number_5_3) . Possibly, all version 5.X will be oriented toward modification and experimentation with the main tags of the list. The difference with the number of pages is mostly the separation of the "heaps of references", not adding new ones.

The First section engenders the sections "ALGEBRAIC STRUCTS", "REAL NUMBER LINE" and "MATHEMATICAL RELATIONS". The Geometrical section split into "THE CURVY, THE ROUND AND THE HOLEY", "DIAGRAMS, ICONS AND CIRCUITS", "KNOTS AND GRAPHS", "SPACES AND CONTINUA", "TURISTIC", "THE POLYHEDRIC, THE SYNTHETIC AND THE COORDINATED", "OFF-TOPIC AND CURIOSITIES", "MIND, BRAIN AND NUMBERS" and "ARRANGEMENTS AND PUZZLES"

Still not too satisfied, and keenly expectant of other possible Tags. In case of a proposed solution, just propose the Tags/Labels, and I will do the migration of references to their respective classification.